# Strange css fixed behaviour

Tags: html, css

I have this super simple piece of code:

```
<body>
<div style="position:fixed; width: 100%; height: 40px; background: #333"></div>

<div style='margin-top:40px; border: 1px solid green'>
Some contents!<br>Some contents!<br>Some contents!<br>
</div>

</body>
```

But somehow the fixed div has a margin of 40px and overlap the second div! Would anyone please point out what I have missed here?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hoangkhanh/zHkkH/

Thanks!

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote?

Comment: Here you have `position:fixed` and in fiddle you have `position:absolute`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `position:absolute` set against the top div with no `top:0` position set. Try this:

```
<body>
<div style="position:absolute; width: 100%; height: 40px; background: #333; top: 0"></div>

<div style='margin-top:40px; border: 1px solid green'>
Some contents!<br>Some contents!<br>Some contents!<br>
</div>

</body>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zHkkH/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Add a top, left, right, or bottom css attribute to the fixed div.

For example

```
{
    top: 0; /*Fixes it to the top*/
}
```